# PHP (Opencart) условие в реальном времени

Tags: php, opencart

```
  <?php if($products) { ?>
  <a href="/cart">Моя корзина</a>
  <?php } else { ?>
  <a href="" onclick="return false;">В корзине нет товаров</a>
  <?php } ?>
```

Добрый ночи, имеется такой код. Код рабочий, но что бы он работал нужно обновлять страницу. Можно ли как то в режиме реального времени выполнять этот код?

Comment: почитайте про javascript, и стоит давать больше информации при каких условиях это должно происходить, ваш код, что где и когда, так больше шансов что люди вам помогут, а так как говорится "тут экстрасенсов нет"